# XMLTV GUI or Console EPG downloader fails only when run from Windows 10 Scheduled Tasks

Tags: windows-10, scheduled-tasks

I'm using the [XMLTV GUI grabber](http://www.birtles.org.uk/xmltv/) to fetch TV program schedule guide (EPG) information from Schedules Direct (North America) for my PVR software under Windows 10. I have no problems at all doing this interactively. Data files are generated that include all the desired information.

However, when run as a scheduled task--either XmltvConsole.exe or XmltvGui.exe /Grab fetch no data, and log messages something like

```
5:15:01 - 0 programs found
...
5:15:02 - No programs found, aborting xml writing
```

which would normally indicate that channels are not configured for the selected grabber. Of course, in the GUI, I see that I've added every available channel to my selected channels list.

I've made sure that the scheduled task is set to run as my user account whether I'm logged in or not, and I've tried various settings for the "Run in" directory box in the scheduled task: I've used the program's directory under C:\Program Files (x86), my user account's home folder, and nothing at all. I've verified that the task appears to run without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution to my own problem, though I'm not really satisfied with it. XMLTV GUI is a pre-Windows 10 program that tries to store its own settings in the

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\XMLTV GUI\settings\
```

folder hierarchy. Windows 10 does not permit this and redirects the file writes to

```
C:\Users\[my-user-name]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\XMLTV GUI\settings\
```

path. This works seamlessly during an interactive user session.

The cause of the problem with XMLTV GUI seems to be that the VirtualStore redirection either does not work for scheduled tasks or is somehow bypessed by XmltvGui.exe and XmltvConsole.exe, even when the task is configured to run as a specific user with their username and password entered.

Using Windows Explorer and allowing access to myself when prompted by UAC, I have found that I can fix the problem by copying the channels.lua and userchannels.txt files from

```
C:\Users\[my-user-name]\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\Program Files (x86)\XMLTV GUI\settings\NA_SD
```

to

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\XMLTV GUI\settings\NA_SD
```

This has to be repeated after every change to my channels settings, and so it's less than ideal, though it does work around the problem.